# Wordpress Blog :: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: wordpress, internal-server-error

I am getting this error message while trying to access a wordpress blog which is installed in a directory. Is this due to .htaccess or something? Any help is appreciated.

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@xxxxx.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at xxxx.com Port 80'

Answer (score 5):

This is almost always a problem with your Apache configuration. Errors originating in PHP won’t trigger the Apache 5xx handler, which is what you’re seeing.

Unfortunately, without more information, your problem is impossible to diagnose. I’d recommend that you:

1. **Check the logs.** First thing! It should give you a better idea where your problem is.
2. Stop and restart Apache. If there is a problem with permissions on something Apache needs write access to (logs), it could **completely fail to start**. This should give you the proper motivation to fix the problem, particularly if there are other VirtualHosts on that Apache.
3. Move your `.htaccess` file(s) somewhere else. If Apache works, you know it’s a problem with that file.

Comment: Actually these errors sometimes occur because of problems with PHP, so it might be the culprit after all.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're getting some sort of PHP error but PHP isn't set to display errors.  You'll want to check your Apache logs for detailed error info.

The mostly likely culprit is that you're missing some prerequisite for running WordPress, although all you should really need is Apache, MySQL, & mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix it by adding the following line to my .htaccess file:

> php_value memory_limit 128M

Russ

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it could be anything. Do static pages on the site work properly.

Have you checked the server logs.

I think it is likely to do with php. If static pages are there then possibly your config for wordpress is incorrectly configured or files missing.

Has php be working? Did the blog work and then stop? Did you get through the install process?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening to me RIGHT NOW.

As to from what I know, my hosting providers did a DNS change and so I'm waiting for the DNS to propagate, it's been like three hours and still zero.

Blog is showing ok, apache is up and working, I just can't get access into the WP Admin area.

If it does get fixed by tomorrow, I'll reply here so it can be of help for others.

Edit: I just fixed my problem.

In my case it was determined that the Fast Contact Form plug-in was creating the problem. I modified the folder name from si-contact-form to si-contact-form-hold then I regained WP Admin access.

After that I created a php.ini file with this string inside 'memory=64MB' and saved that into the wp-admin folder.

Manually deleted the si-contact-form-hold (to avoid possible corrupted files) and reinstalled the Fast Contact Form.

All my settings were already there and everything is back up and running good!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look at http://zemalf.com/1470/wordpress-htaccess-the-definite-guide/, and look for the paragraph which says something like "Good and default .htaccess looks like this...."

Answer (score 1):

My issue was a little bit different. I had an `.htaccess` file inside the `wp-admin` directory. I deleted the `.htaccess` inside of `wp-admin` and that fixed my problems.

Answer (score 1):

Check wordpress files ownership for the user are correct or not.

In linux `ls -laZ` command will display the ownership.

For setting the ownership for a folder use this command

```
chown -R username:username /user/username/public_html/
```

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP 500 error could be caused by a great many things. Have you changed your .htaccess file recently? If you try to use a .htaccess feature that is disabled on your host, that is one possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

Some more points

- Blog has been running successfully. Just observed this problem since yesterday.
- Blog is in a directory so it works something like this www.xyz.com/blog. Apparently www.xyz.com is working perfectly.

Update on logs

Getting these two errors in the logs:

1. File does not exist: /home/directory/public_html/500.shtml
2. /home/sub-directory/public_html/sub-directory/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad argument line '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}!-f'
3. /home/directory/public_html/sub-directory/.htaccess: # without matching # section

How do I restart apache on cpanel ?

Comment: Can you post the contents of the .htaccess file?

Comment: Did you set up a new plugin or change the perma link structure? Again it's hard to trouble shot without a copy of the .htaccess, but I would be look at what has changed since you set up the blog.

Answer (score 0):

```
        memory = 64MB;
```

The above line inside a php.ini file uploaded to the wp-admin folder solved my problem. I was not being able to log into the dashboard either through /wp-admin or /wp-login.php, and was getting a HTTP server error 500.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple causes for this, I just solved mine, after 2-3 hours of going crazy.
I had another WP instance in **a subdirectory inside the main WP instance** (in the root folder).

- Have checked / deleted .htaccess
- deleted plugin folder

In the end, it was to do with the permission of the subfolder in which second instance was running. It was originally **775** (write permission for group), I had to change it to **755** (no write permission for group) and this finally fixed it, like magic.

This is of course just one of possible the answers to your question, I wanted to write it down though as I didn't find it explicitly written anywhere so it might save others some time.